# Less redundant way of putting this

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have this code that stores the checked value of a checkbox in localStorage.

How would I shrink it?

```
$('#OSPone').click(function(e){
    saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
    getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
});

$("#OSPtwo").click(function(e){
    saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
    getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
});

$("#OSPthree").click(function(e){
    saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
    getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
});

$("#OSPfour").click(function(e){
    saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
    getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
});
```

Settings functions:

```
function saveSettings(aVal, aKey){
    localStorage.setItem(aVal, JSON.stringify(aKey))
}

function getSettings(aKey){
    var str = localStorage.getItem(aKey);
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it. I've put them in order of the best way of doing it in my opinion.

## 1. Classes

Apply a class to all the current elements (`#OSPone` - `#OSPfour`). For example, `.settingsBtn`.

***HTML***

```
<input type="checkbox" id="#OSPone" class="settingsBtn" />
<input type="checkbox" id="#OSPtwo" class="settingsBtn" />
<input type="checkbox" id="#OSPthree" class="settingsBtn" />
<input type="checkbox" id="#OSPfour" class="settingsBtn" />
```

***JavaScript***

```
$('.settingsBtn').click(function(e) {
    saveSettings(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.checked);
    getSettings(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

## 2. Select Checkboxes

Assuming you are using checkboxes and on each one you want to update the settings on click, you can select checkboxes accordingly.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
    saveSettings(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.checked);
    getSettings(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

## 3. `^=` Selector

You can select elements that have an ID that starts with `OSP`.

```
$('[id^=OSP]').click(function(e) {
    saveSettings(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.checked);
    getSettings(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

## 4. Single Selector

Combine all selectors into one.

```
$('#OSPone, #OSPtwo, #OSPthree, #OSPfour').click(function(e) {
    saveSettings(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.checked);
    getSettings(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function updateSettings(e) {
    saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
    getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
}

$('#OSPone, #OSPtwo, $OSPthree, #OSPfour').on('click', updateSettings);
```

Or you can add a class or data-attribute to those elements and use that as your selector. Whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to all of the elements, then handle the event for that selector:

```
$(".settingCheck").click(function(e){
    saveSettings(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.checked);
    getSettings(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
function storeVal(element) {
    $(element).click(function(e){
        saveSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"], e["currentTarget"]["checked"]);
        getSettings(e["currentTarget"]["id"]);
    });
}

storeVal('#OSPone, #OSPtwo, $OSPthree, #OSPfour');
```